# Boot Camp, Windows install not finding Boot Camp partition

Tags: bootcamp, windows, partition

I got an iMac 27'' Retina 5k (late 2014) and want to install Windows 10 using Boot Camp. I'm running on macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

BCA completes the download of the Windows support file successfully, creates the BC partition and starts up with the initial Windows 10 setup until the setup asks 'Where do you want to install Windows?'. In the list the shown the boot camp partition does not appear (see below) and I terminated the process. I ran diskutil list after my Mac rebooted and could see that BCA created the partition.

[image: Windows setup window]

A second problem is that the size of the partition created by BCA was about 140 GB greater than I actually selected it to be (selected 240 GB/created 380 GB).

Any help or feedback is appreciated...

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question.